# Web interface for using django's filter function

Tags: django

Is there any interface that exists already to facilitate selecting objects with django's filter function? I'd like to have the power of the filter function in my app, but don't really feel like writing a clumsy facade to just pass things through to the filter function.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a big big fan of [django-filter](http://github.com/alex/django-filter/tree/master) and know I'm not the only one who hopes this will be included as a contrib app in Django.

Answer (score 0):

The [admin interface](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) is pretty close to what you want I think. It comes with django out of the box.